# How to consume and export an array of objects inside my class in Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm setting up an application with Spring boot and Angular to study front end.
I have some REST APIs providing me objects of students and objects of classes.
How can I properly declare these objects and arrays and how can I post them back to my spring app?

What I have so far:

My API at localhost:8080/api/students/ populated in back end is returning:

```
[
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "john",
        "classes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "math"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "english"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "paul",
        "classes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "math"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "science"
            }
        ]

    }
]
```

My API at localhost:8080/api/classes/ populated in back end is returning:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "math"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "english"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "science"
    }
]
```

and this is my front end

**Student.ts**

```js
import { Classes} from "./classes";

export class Student{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    classes: Classes[];
}
```

Am I declaring classes right as an array inside Student?

**Classes.ts**

```js
export class Classes{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

**create-form.component.html**

```html
<h3>Create Student</h3>
<div [hidden]="submitted" style="width: 400px;">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="student.name" name="name">
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="classes">Classes</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="classes" name="classes" required [(ngModel)]="student.classes">
        <option *ngFor="let class of classes | async"> {{ class.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </div> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**create-form.component.ts**

```js
student: Student= new Student();
classes: Observable<Classes[]>;
submitted = false;
constructor(private studentService: StudentService) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.classes= this.studentService.getClassesList();
}
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.save();
}
save() {
    this.studentService.createStudent(this.student)
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
    this.student= new Student();
}
```

I can show the list of classes in the select, but after selecting one and submiting I get

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/students/create", ok: false, …}
error:
error: "Bad Request"
message: "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token ...
path: "/api/students/create"
status: 400
```

Can somebody help me and explain what am I doing wrong? Also, is there any other option to select many classes in a form? Currently I can only select one!

---

Updating answer to @ashish.gd
This is the preview of my network tab when I post without the the ngmodel bind in classes

```
{id: 8, name: "johnny", classes: null"}
id: 8
classes: null
name: "johnny"
```

And this is the header of my network tab

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/students/create
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/add
```

Comment: The `student` object you are posting to the server contains an `classes` property which is of type `array`. Most probably your server is not expecting this input format. Try doing `JSON.stringify(this.student)` before posting to the server.

Comment: @ashish.gd if I remove the `[(ngModel)]="student.classes"` from my select I can post my `student` object without any errors, I just get a `null` in my `classes` property

Comment: Can you post the http request or the request body as shown in the network tab

Comment: @ashish.gd Yes, I updated the post with the informations you asked, both the preview and the header

Answer (score 0):

The `select` html element is binding the selected value to `student.classes` which is basically a simple string. Due to this your request object is getting created with classes as string. For example:

```
{
    id: 8,
    name: "johnny",
    classes: "science"
}
```

where as your API endpoint is expecting the `classes` property to be a list or array.

Hence the `JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token;`

Changing your request object to pass the `classes` property as array should solve your error. Example:

```
{
    id: 8,
    name: "johnny",
    classes: ["science"]
}
```

However, pushing selected items into array is not possible by simple binding. You will need to convert the `classes` property from string to array before making the api in the component.

Comment: Thanks to this answer I was able to focus on my real problem. I created an array from my object by subscribing to it, then I used that array to show the data on the page.